# How to render a jade block(section) using links?

Tags: express, pug

I was hoping someone had any insight on this basic approach. Sample scenario:

I have a dashboard template with menu links a(href "/page") and I want to click the links to render a different section/view on the template. I used block content...but does it need a specific route?

Comment: Jade is a templating language whose only purpose is to let you write HTML a little easily. Clicking on <a> link can't affect what Jade renders, it has already been rendered. What you're wanting to do is purely a client-side html/dom/javascript task. [like this](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: I definitely understand what your saying, yes your right. However, how does the extend, block or include come in play? I simply want to render a SECTION on the same page without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the content of the page on click of the link without the page getting refreshed.

In that case, no you can't do it using `block content`. 
The purpose of `block content` is to apply inheritance in your templates. 
The typical use of `block content` would be creating a layout and then creating more specific page from the layout. [This](http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/) is what the official documentation says.

The reason why you cannot do it because, jade is server side templating library. This resolves the `block content` on server. Once rendered in client, the html looses all the information that was specific to jade (which is obvious because its an html afterall).

What you can do here is

Create a `/page.jade` and make a ajax call to a service. That service should return an already compiled html string. Since you are using jade, you can easily use `jade.compile(source, options)` to template / generate html.

Jade API documentation [here](http://jade-lang.com/api/)